# PyAudio in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have written a program for speech to text in which I use speech recognition by pycharm ask for PyAudio so I tried to do so . But PyAudio in pycharm is not getting installed

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting installed"?

Answer (score 1):

Sounddevice is easier for speech recognition because of it's simplicity. However if you really need pyaudio use

```
pip<python version> install pyaudio #in the terminal
```

if that does not work then check what python you are using in pycharm by looking at the python console tab. In this case I am using python 3.6.
[image]

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import speechrecognition as sr
s = sr.Recognizer()
audio = sd.rec(int(time*44100),44100)
sd.wait()
sf.write("audio.wav",audio,time*44100)
audio = sr.AudioFile("audio.wav")
with audio as file:
    audio = s.record(file)
#wit.ai is a free speech recognition api from facebook and works almost as good as google.
text = s.recognize_wit(audio, key="*********")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to configure a Python interpreter

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 0):

Use pipwin to install it

first...
`pip install pipwin`

then...
`pipwin install pyaudio`

I had this issue as well.  I found this answer buried in the comments section of the following youtube video: [Build an audio spectrum analyzer with python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AShHJdSIxkY)

Answer (score 0):

Just an add on to Nicholas's answer, instead of `pipwin install pyaudio`, `py -m pipwin install pyaudio` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

try to install pipwin then try to install pyaudio
commands in terminal :
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio