# python program for speech to text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I was trying to build simple AI which listen to me and do some work like playing music and opening youtube videos. I have used speech recognition  but the error is comming asking for PyAudio and it is not getting installed in pycharm .

How do I  install pyaudio in 
pycharm?
Alternative way would work too.

Comment: you don't have to install anything in pycharm. Everything needs to be installed in your environment (virtual or systemwide). just use `pip install pyaudio`

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions or post same question twice 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336740/pyaudio-in-pycharm

Answer (score -1):

Just write this command in your cmd:

> pip install pyaudio

it worked for me